# How a scanner can be implemented with a custom split

Tags: go

I have a log file, and I need to parse each record in it using golang.
Each record begin with "#", and a record can span one or more lines :

```
# Line1
# Line2
Continued line2
Continued line2
# line3
.....
```

Some code :), I'm a beginner

```
   f, _ := os.Open(mylog)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(f)
    var queryRec string

    for scanner.Scan() {
            line := scanner.Text()

            if strings.HasPrefix(line, "# ") && len(queryRec) == 0 {
                    queryRec = line
            } else if !strings.HasPrefix(line, "# ") && len(queryRec) == 0 {
                    fmt.Println("There is a big problem!!!")
            } else if !strings.HasPrefix(line, "# ") && len(queryRec) != 0 {
                    queryRec += line
            } else if strings.HasPrefix(line, "# ") && len(queryRec) != 0 {
                    queryRec = line
            }
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Show us the code you have already written, explain what problems you are having, and why you think it might be hard.

Comment: I'm trying to read each record, and put it in a mysql database @PedroLobito

Comment: Added some code @gbulmer

Comment: Now, what's the problem? Errors? Wrong output?

Comment: My questions : 1. How can I handle the last line from the log file?  2. There is a more optimized/elegant way to achieve the same goal?

Comment: You could have asked this question in a more general sense by asking how a scanner can be implemented with a custom split. It would apply to more people who are interested in a permutation of this problem. Consider editing your question to make it general and use your particular instance as an example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) type has a function called [Split](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Split) which allows you to pass a [`SplitFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc) to determine how the scanner will split the given byte slice. The default [`SplitFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc) is the [`ScanLines`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#ScanLines) which you can see the [implementation source](https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan.go?s=9745:9823#L280). From this point you can write your own [`SplitFunc`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#SplitFunc) to break the `bufio.Reader` content based on your specific format.

```
func crunchSplitFunc(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {

    // Return nothing if at end of file and no data passed
    if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
        return 0, nil, nil
    }

    // Find the index of the input of a newline followed by a 
    // pound sign.
    if i := strings.Index(string(data), "\n#"); i >= 0 {
        return i + 1, data[0:i], nil
    }

    // If at end of file with data return the data
    if atEOF {
        return len(data), data, nil
    }

    return
}
```

You can see the full implementation of the example at https://play.golang.org/p/ecCYkTzme4. The documentation provides all the insight needed to implement something like this.

Comment: Thanks @benjic. Elegant solution that works as expected :)

Comment: This will be problematic when the input data contains multiple newlines before `#`s.

Answer (score 10):

Slightly optimized solution of [Ben Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069759/11844755) and [sto-b-doo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127669/11844755)

Conversion of byte slice to string appears to be quite heavy operation.

In my app for log processing it became a bottleneck.

Just keeping data in bytes gives **~1500%** performance boost to my app.

```
func SplitAt(substring string) func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
    searchBytes := []byte(substring)
    searchLen := len(searchBytes)
    return func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {
        dataLen := len(data)

        // Return nothing if at end of file and no data passed
        if atEOF && dataLen == 0 {
            return 0, nil, nil
        }

        // Find next separator and return token
        if i := bytes.Index(data, searchBytes); i >= 0 {
            return i + searchLen, data[0:i], nil
        }

        // If we're at EOF, we have a final, non-terminated line. Return it.
        if atEOF {
            return dataLen, data, nil
        }

        // Request more data.
        return 0, nil, nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Ben Campbell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069759/6672339) wrapped into a func that returns a splitfunc for a substring:

[demo on play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/FY-TfF_sVcB)

Improvement suggestions welcome

```
// SplitAt returns a bufio.SplitFunc closure, splitting at a substring
// scanner.Split(SplitAt("\n# "))
func SplitAt(substring string) func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {

    return func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {

        // Return nothing if at end of file and no data passed
        if atEOF && len(data) == 0 {
            return 0, nil, nil
        }

        // Find the index of the input of the separator substring
        if i := strings.Index(string(data), substring); i >= 0 {
            return i + len(substring), data[0:i], nil
        }

        // If at end of file with data return the data
        if atEOF {
            return len(data), data, nil
        }

        return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully an improvement (maybe readability) over [stu0292's improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51127669/5754723)
And uses the final token signal.

```
// SplitAt returns a bufio.SplitFunc closure, splitting at a substring
// scanner.Split(SplitAt("\n#"))
func SplitAt(substring string) func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance    int, token []byte, err error) {

   return func(data []byte, atEOF bool) (advance int, token []byte, err error) {

      // Find the index of the input of the separator substring
       if i := strings.Index(string(data), substring); i >= 0 {
         return i + len(substring), data[0:i], nil
       }

       if !atEOF {
         return 0, nil, nil
       }
     return len(data), data, bufio.ErrFinalToken
  }
}
```